# reading a 2048-bit Diffie-Hellman prime number from a buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to use the telegram API to support telegram calls directly from out system. In order to perform the call, the library requires e2e encryption. so I am calling a method to get a 2048-bit Diffie-Hellman prime number from the api. However, the number is coming as a buffer and I want to convert it to be a 2048bit prime number. here is the code

```
async requestCall(userId: string) {
    try {
      const dhConfig = await this.invoke(
        new Api.messages.GetDhConfig({
          randomLength: 32
        })
      );

      // convert p to number
      // @ts-expect-error ignore
      const p = dhConfig.p as Buffer;
      // convert p to integer

      const pInt = p.readInt32BE(0);

      // @ts-expect-error ignore
      const g = dhConfig.g;

      // chose random value between 1 and p-1
      const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pInt - 1)) + 1;

      // calculate g^a mod p
      const ga = Math.pow(g, a) % pInt;
      this.ga = ga;

      // get the ga hash SHA256 of g^a mod p as 32 bytes
      const gaHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(ga.toString()).digest();

      // save in the session
      this.a = a;
      this.p = pInt;

      // request the call
      await this.invoke(
        new Api.phone.RequestCall({
          userId,
          randomId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
          gAHash: gaHash,
          protocol: new Api.PhoneCallProtocol({
            udpP2p: true,
            udpReflector: true,
            minLayer: 65,
            maxLayer: 65,
            libraryVersions: ['1.0.0', '2.0.0', '3.0.0', '4.0.0']
          })
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('[Telegram Client] [call] error: ', err);
    }
  }
```

the number that I am getting is a negative number and it is most probably wrong. I also tried to convert it to string and then number but it did not work. so, the question is, how to get the prime number from that buffer?

Comment: What is the desired final result for the 2048 bit prime number that starts out in a buffer?  A regular Javascript number won't hold a 2048 bit integer so "converting to a number" isn't making sense here.  The mantissa in a Javascript number only holds 54 bits of precision.

Comment: @jfriend00 
in their explanation, I need to take this number, make sure that it is prime and use it to calculate another value that will be used for the hash.

https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/video-calls.

"A executes messages.getDhConfig to find out the 2048-bit Diffie-Hellman prime p and generator g. The client is expected to check whether p is a safe prime and perform all the security checks necessary for secret chats."

Comment: Well, you cannot use regular Javascript numbers for a 2048-bit number.  You could use the BigInt type and use only BigInt math.  But, more typically, you would leave it in the Buffer and just pass the Buffer to various crypto functions to let them manipulate it in whatever fashion you need to.  You would not normally manipulate the 2048-bit value directly.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write this from scratch rather than use an existing library to do this?  Perhaps something like this [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram) and [here](https://gram.js.org/tl/phone/CreateGroupCall).  Or perhaps study how that library works?